# getting top and left position of colorbox at runtime

Tags: javascript, colorbox

Been trying to get the top and left coordinates colorbox loaded content, but I keep getting either 0 or auto.

I'm executing the following in `onComplete` callback:

```
var cboxLeft =  $('#cboxContent').css('left');//.position().left;
var  cboxTop =  $('#cboxContent').css('top');//.position().top;

console.log( 'cboxLeft: ' + cboxLeft + '    cboxTop: ' + cboxTop );
```

Right now console gives me: `cboxLeft: 0px cboxTop: 0px`

What I'm really after is appending custom close button to BODY. I need it accessible outside the cboxLoaded* area and visible. Hence trying to get position of content once colorbox is done with it.

Comment: Please, add more code. It'd be great if you'll attach jsfiddle or codepen with code.

It seems to be classical mistake - get data before rendering element.

Answer (score 0):

`.css()` will not return these properties. You'll have to use .offset() instead.

So the code should look like:

```
var cboxLeft =  $('#cboxContent').offset().left;
var  cboxTop =  $('#cboxContent').offset().top;

console.log( 'cboxLeft: ' + cboxLeft + '    cboxTop: ' + cboxTop );
```

**Note:** This gives the position relative to the document. If you want where it is on the current viewport (current view of the browser window), you might want to subtract `window.scrollX` and `window.scrollY` respectively.